# Display Photos android code

Tags: java, android

How do u access the photos from internal storage on your phone
and display it

Comment: Please give a bit of context, what are you trying to do?

Comment: ehh, trying to display all the photos that are on my phone when u click a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a basic example supossing you have a folder called "myPics" and inside it a picture called "clone.jpg"

```
File imageFile = new File("/sdcard/myPics/clone.png");
if (imageFile.exists()){
    //load clone.jpg into your ImageView.
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), bitmap);
    myimageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    myimageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

Comment: @PaulLammertsma                                                                hey cheers, but its only showing a black screen, do u know why this is?